# Proper entry point in modern ecmascript 6

Tags: standards, program-entry-point, ecmascript-6

Assuming EcmaScript 6, a "compiler" and that I'd like to follow some convention akin to C or C++ when `main` is usually a function.

Most tutorials I've found ([1](https://gist.github.com/danawoodman/9cfddb1a0c934a35f31a), [2](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html)) suggest adding your "components" somewhere in the `<body>` which I found ugly and undestand as a concession for new comers.

Anyway, suppose I have my compiler configured something like:

```
{
    entry: [
      "./src/main.js"
    ],
    output: {
        filename: "app.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js?$/, loaders: ['babel',], exclude: /node_modules/ },
        ]
    },
}
```

How would you write your `main.js` so it, Starts after DOM is read,  and be included only before closing `<head>`, not anywhere in the document?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with ES6.

Comment: I assume your compiler only writes to `app.js`, not to your html files? Just place your script imports in them as you always would.